# Post callback not triggered using rxjs observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to debug the response from a post call. The post succeedes and the response is shown inside the response tab in the Chrome developer tools but the promise callback is never triggered.

Any idea why the callback is not triggered?

Here is the subscription:

```
this.mService.uploadFiles([file.name, new Blob()]).subscribe((response: any) => {
      var myResponse = response;
//Do something with response
    },
      error => {
        var err = `Failed with status = ${error.status}`;
      });
```

Calling the Rest API:

```
public uploadFiles(files: any): Observable<any> {

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', files[1], files[0]);

        return this.http.post(`${this.myServiceEndpoint + "api/uploadFiles"}`, formData, {
            observe: 'response'
        }).pipe(map(response => response))
    }
```

I am actually getting the following error even though the POST succeeds. Probable related to how the service is subscribing.

```
core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:15)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:43)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1707)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)
```

[UPDATE]

Below is the server side code for the called Azure Function

```
       [FunctionName("UploadFiles")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("Testing");
}
```

In this case Chrome displays the Testing string in the response tab. The callback is however not triggered.

... but if change the code to only return a OkResult the callback is triggered. So it seems the error appears only if the OkResult contains a payload. Any clue why this is failing?

```
return (ActionResult)new OkResult();
```

Comment: Do you subscribe to the observable anywhere? That is one of the reasons this could happen

Comment: Hi @Askirkela thanks for your reply. I am subscriping to the observable in the upper code example. Is something else needed?

Comment: Are you uploading the file to the same place where the FE is deployed?

Comment: Currently I am uploading it locally to a .net core API. The call gets through and this part is fine even the response gets back to Chrome but the callback is simply not triggered.

Comment: BTW the `map(response => response)` is redundant.

Comment: Have you checked if there is anything inside the error in the subscription, because this behavior seems a lot like CORS related issue

Comment: I actually get a subscription error in the chrome console but the error callback in the subscription does not get triggered. See the updated question with the error.

Comment: Are you using jwt interceptor ? What is your response type from backend ?
This error is because you have different response type in your response

Comment: This error typically happens when you use eg. `catchError()`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` (or any operator with a projection function that expect you to return an Observable) and forget to use `return`. This means that the problem is somewhere else and not in what you showed in your question.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace it actually shows that it's thrown from `catchError()`. So somewhere in your code you have `catchError()` where you don't return any Observable

Comment: @doorman if you use map after getting a response it would fix your issue so what i am saying is you can use `map` inside your subscribe arrow function

Comment: Hi @Martin you were right the error was due to missing json formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to convert the response to json format on the server side (thought this was default json) and escaping the string quotes because the Angular interseptor was expecting json:

```
 [FunctionName("UploadFiles")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
        {
            var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Testing");
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(jsonResponse);
}
```

and the callback is triggered successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try do return response

```
public uploadFiles(files: any): Observable<any> {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files[1], files[0]);
    return this.http.post(`${this.myServiceEndpoint + "api/uploadFiles"}`, formData, {headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})}).pipe(
            map((response: Response) => {
                return response;
            })
            )

}
```

whenever you do map in service like this do return that value so that mapped value will be return where you subscribing this service

**EDIT**

Try passing headers since you are passing file object in api

Comment: @Aarash he is returning the response.

Comment: hi @Aarsh thanks for your suggestion I tried this as well but without success. It's a bit strange if I call a GET method the callback gets triggered. I suppose POST should work in the same way?

Comment: It is bit strange to me too @ХристиянХристов because In my application without return it was not working so I did return and boommmm I am getting response so I thought that might be problem there. I am doing same as you are doing doorman and I am getting response as well. can you please provide stackblitz to we can have look into it

Comment: Hi @Aarsh thanks for your suggestion, see the above error I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

**component**

```
this.mService.uploadFiles([file.name, new Blob()]).subscribe((response: any) => {
      var myResponse = response;
// here we are doing other operations like filtering and mapping etc..
      myResponse.pipe(map(result => { console.log(result); }))
    },
      error => {
        var err = `Failed with status = ${error.status}`;
      });
```

**service**

```
public uploadFiles(files: any): Observable<any> {

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', files[1], files[0]);

        return this.http.post(`${this.myServiceEndpoint + "api/uploadFiles"}`, formData, {
            observe: 'response'
        });
    }
```

Comment: this will not work, because `uploadFIles` return observable (the http call) for which observable we subscribe and the response of http response that you are suggesting to `map` is a js object, not an observable, that we can pipe.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but still getting the same error

Comment: @doorman try to remove the `observe` and add `HttpHeaders` there and try again and let me know if it is working or not

Comment: @YashRami still the same but I noticed the callback triggers if there is no payload in the server response. See updated question.